# $L^p$-norm under the heat flow

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, parabolic-pde, heat-equation

Let $(M, g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold.

Assume that $u_0$ is a positive smooth function on $M$ and let $u_t = e^{t \Delta} u_0$ be the solution to the heat equation on $(M, g)$ with initial data $u_0$.

Given $2a > 1$, is it true that the function
$$
f: t \mapsto \int_M (u_t)^{2a}
$$
is a convex function?

This question gives an answer to [Functional decaying under the heat flow (?)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301673/functional-decaying-under-the-heat-flow) in the case $p=2$. Indeed,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dt} \int_M u_t^{2a} dv
 &=& 2 a \int_M u_t^{2a-1} \Delta u_t dv\\
 &=& -2 a \int_M \left\langle \nabla\left(u_t^{2a-1}\right), \nabla u_t\right\rangle dv\\
 &=& -2 a (2a-1) \int_M u_t^{2a-2} \left|\nabla u_t\right|^2 dv\\
 &=& -2 a (2a-1) \int_M \left|u_t^{a-1}\nabla u_t\right|^2 dv\\
 &=& -\frac{4a-2}{a} \int_M \left|\nabla (u_t^a)\right|^2 dv.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, showing that $f$ is convex means that $f'' \geq 0$ or, equivalently, from the previous calculation
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \int_M \left|\nabla (u_t^a)\right|^2 dv \leq 0.
$$

The value of $a$ for interest in my problem is
$$
2a = 2^* + 2 = 4 \frac{n-1}{n-2},
$$
where $n$ is the dimension of the manifold and $2^* = \frac{2n}{n-2}$.

Comment: I doubt about this. Take $M=\mathbb{R}$, and let $p=3$. then if my calculation is correct , the second derivative in $t$, at point $t=0$ is $C\int_{\mathbb{R}} (u'_{0}(x))^{3} dx$ where $u_{0}$ is your initial data, and $C>0$ is universal constant.  Now it can have an arbitrary sign. For example, start with even $u_{0}$ and perturb it slightly.

Comment: @Paata: Notice that $M$ is required to be compact.

Comment: Ops, this I missed. You are right.

Comment: How is this function even defined if $u_t$ is negative and $p$ is not an integer?

Comment: @MichaelRenardy: Remember that the heat kernel $h$ is positive at all points. Since $u_0$ is positive, it follows that $u_t (x) = \int h(t,x,y) u_0 (y) \ \mathrm d y$ is also positive, so your issue does not occur.

Comment: @Paata: There is something wrong with your calculation. Each time you take a time derivative of the expression, you get two more spatial derivatives, So the second order derivative of this expression should contain 4 space derivatives.

Comment: @Romain, you are right. I made a mistake in my calculation because of not having a pen and paper with me.  Let us try one more time for $M=\mathbb{R}$. So $h(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} u^{3}dx$. $h'(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} 3u^{2} u_{t} dx =\int_{\mathbb{R}} 3u^{2} u'' dx = -6\int_{\mathbb{R}}u u'^{2}$. Now $h''(t) = -6 \int_{\mathbb{R}}(u'' u'^{2} + 2u u' u''')=6 \int_{\mathbb{R}}(u'' u'^{2} + 2u u''^{2})$, Notice that $u'' u'^{2} + 2u u''^{2} =\frac{4}{3}\frac{u'' (u^{3/2})''}{\sqrt{u}}$. Looks  like integral of the latter can have an arbitrary sign

Comment: @AlexM. I see, I got confused by notation and interpreted the subscript t as a time derivative.

Comment: @Paata $u''u'^2$ integrates to $0$ and, obviously, $\int u(u'')^2\ge 0$

Comment: Romain, I'm hopelessly confused which $p$ is from this problem and which is from the other one. Can you use two different letters, please? (say $q$ for this one and $p$ for the other one) :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I didn't do any miscalculations I believe I have proven the case $1\leq p\leq 2$. I will write $u$ instead of $u_t$. Let $(p)_k=p(p-1)\ldots(p-k+1)$ and
$$
w=\begin{pmatrix}
pu^{p-1}\Delta^2 u\\ (p)_2u^{p-2}\nabla\Delta u\cdot \nabla u\\ (p)_2u^{p-2}(\Delta u)^2\\ (p)_3u^{p-3}(\Delta u)|\nabla u|^2\\ (p)_4u^{p-4}|\nabla u|^4\end{pmatrix}
$$
For $v=u^p$ we have
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \Delta^2v\\ \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Delta v\\ \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)^2v\end{pmatrix}=
 \begin{pmatrix}1 & 4 & 3 & 6 & 1\\ 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0\\1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}w\\
$$
Hence
$$
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)^2v = 2 \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Delta v-\Delta^2 v+\begin{pmatrix}2 & 4 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}(p)_2u^{p-2}(\Delta u)^2\\ (p)_3u^{p-3}(\Delta u)|\nabla u|^2\\ (p)_4u^{p-4}|\nabla u|^4\end{pmatrix}.\\
$$
For $1\leq p\leq 2$ we have $(p)_2\geq 0, (p)_4\geq 0$. We try to prove that the last term is positive. Note that $\sqrt{2(2-p)(3-p)}\geq 2(2-p)$. Hence by AM-GM
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
2(p)_2u^{p-2}(\Delta u)^2+ (p)_4u^{p-4}|\nabla u|^4&\geq& \sqrt{2(p)_2u^{p-2}(\Delta u)^2(p)_4u^{p-4}|\nabla u|^4}\\
&=&2(p)_2\sqrt{2(p-2)(p-3)}u^{p-3} |\Delta u||\nabla u|^2 \\
&\geq&2(p)_22(2-p)u^{p-3} (\Delta u)||\nabla u|^2\\
&\geq&4(p)_3u^{p-3}(\Delta u)|\nabla u|^2.
\end{eqnarray}.
$$
Hence we have for $1\leq p \leq 2$
$$
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)^2v \geq 2 \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Delta v-\Delta^2 v
$$
and therefore
$$
\int_M \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)^2v \geq \int_M 2 \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Delta v-\Delta^2 v=\int_M \Delta\left(2 \frac{\partial}{\partial t}v-\Delta v \right)=0
$$

---

Prove for $0\leq p\leq 3$ (added 6.6.2018):

Note that
$$
0=\int_M \nabla\left( (p)_3 u^{p-3} (\nabla u)^3\right)=3\int_M (p)_3 u^{p-3} |\nabla u|^2 (\Delta u)+\int_M (p)_4 u^{p-4} (\nabla u)^4.
$$
Hence we have
$$
\int_M 2(p)_2 u^{p-2} (\Delta u)^2+4 (p)_3 u^{p-3} |\nabla u|^2 (\Delta u)+(p)_4 u^{p-4} (\nabla u)^4\\
=\int_M 2(p)_2 u^{p-2} (\Delta u)^2+(4+3\lambda) (p)_3 u^{p-3} |\nabla u|^2 (\Delta u)+(1+\lambda)(p)_4 u^{p-4} (\nabla u)^4
$$
for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. We try to prove that there exist $\lambda$ such that the integrand is positive everywhere. A sufficient condition is
$$
2(p-2)(p-3)(\lambda+1)\geq \left(\frac{4+3\lambda}{2}\right)^2(p-2)^2\\
\Leftrightarrow 0\geq\frac{9}{4}(p-2)^2\lambda^2+(p-2)(4p-6)\lambda+2(p-2)(p-1),
$$
for which a $\lambda$ exist if and only if
$$
(p-2)^2(4p-6)^2\geq 4\frac{9}{4}(p-2)^2 2(p-2)(p-1)\\
\Leftrightarrow 0\geq p(p-3)  \Leftrightarrow 0\leq p \leq 3.
$$
Hence for $0\leq p \leq 3$ we have
$$
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)^2v \geq 2 \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Delta v-\Delta^2 v+\lambda \nabla\left( (p)_3 u^{p-3} (\nabla u)^3\right)$$
and therefore
$$
\int_M \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)^2v \geq \int_M 2 \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Delta v-\Delta^2 v+\lambda \nabla\left( (p)_3 u^{p-3} (\nabla u)^3\right)=\int_M \Delta\left(2 \frac{\partial}{\partial t}v-\Delta v \right)+\lambda \int_M \nabla\left( (p)_3 u^{p-3} (\nabla u)^3\right)=0
$$

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot ! I will check it next week and come back to you then.

Comment: I believe the second row should be $(1,2,1,1,0)$, not $(1,1,1,2,0)$ (you get the third derivative from the differentiation wrt $t$ of $|\nabla u|^2$ in $\Delta v$, so if there is a $2$ somewhere, it should be on this component).

Comment: @fedja: thx for pointing that out. I corrected my solution. Luckily, the method still seems to work and we even get nicer constants (less fractions).

Comment: @RomainGicquaud Now, let's say we are on the 2D torus with conformal metric (multiply it by something of which the function doesn't depend to raise the dimension, if you insist on $n\ge 3$). Then if the expression is negative at a single point, we can enhance the importance of that point as much as we want by dropping the conformal factor there $A$ times (which will drop the volume form $A^2$ times but enhance the $4$-th order derivatives $A^4$ times. Thus Markus' range looks actually sharp. Am I talking nonsense?

Comment: @fedja: you are right. Set $\widehat{g} = f^2 g$ for some positive function. Then (in 2d) the conformal transformation law for the Laplacian is given by $\widehat{\Delta} u = f^{-2} \Delta u$ and for the measure it gives $d\widehat{v} = f^2 dv$. As a consequence, we have
$$
\int u^{p-2} \left(\widehat{\Delta} u\right)^2 d\widehat{v} = \int u^{p-2} (\Delta u)^2 f^{-2}dv.
$$
And the other two terms pick up the same $f^{-2}$ factor. So if you shrink the metric where the expression is negative, you can make it as negative as you want.

Comment: @RomainGicquaud Which means that your only hope in the range you are interested in is the extra $\lambda \int u^{p-2}|\nabla u|^2$. Of course, it scales differently when going to high frequences, but the fixed metric cannot follow the oscillations, so there is some hope. It's getting rather fascinating :-)

Comment: I extended the proof to $p\in [0,3]$. However this somehow seems to contradict your argument so either of us must be wrong I guess.

Comment: @user35593 There is a big difference between the Euclidean setting and an arbitrary manifold. I believe you can do the Euclidean setting way above $2$ (but not forever), but on the manifold once you have that expression of Markus negative at one point, you can blow it up as described above. You should be careful with those fancy formulae. In particular, the gradients do not necessarily integrate to 0 with respect to the volume any more.

Comment: @fedja: Ok but does then the proof above for $1\leq p\leq 2$ also work on nonflat manifolds?
It would be an interesting question what the maximum in the Euclidean setting is. Do you have a proof that $p=\infty$ does not work?

Comment: @user35593 I hope it does but  I haven't checked that all computations  are legitimate, to be honest. My idea of a non-flat manifold would be a 2D with conformal metric. Ask Romain whether he sees any potential flaw. I agree that the Euclidean setting is interesting to figure out. And no, for this particular case I do not have a counterexample for large $p$.

Comment: If u0 is constant to its maximum on an open ball the derivative of the maximum value wrt time is zero. On the other hand the maximum is monotonically decreasing so the maximum value over time can not be convex at time 0. I was not able to find counterexamples for $p<\infty$.